# cert-manager apply clusterissuer uses wrong service url

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubectl, cert-manager

I have tried different versions of cert-manager, but every time when I want to apply an ClusterIssuer it's pointed to the wrong service.

The service in the log message is: `cert-manger-cert-manager-webhook` and the url is `cert-manger-cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate`, this is obviously wrong. But I don't know how it comes or how I change it.

[log message from kubectl apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu3g9.png)

I also have tried added a conversion, webhook in de CRD but this doesn't solved my issue. Any one an idea what I am doing wrong?

It's managed Kubernetes on Digital Ocean.

All the resources in the namespace:

```
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cert-manager-86b4798576-4s754              1/1     Running   0          23m
pod/cert-manager-cainjector-85656d565c-mvptc   1/1     Running   0          23m
pod/cert-manager-webhook-8665f985d6-lqdqf      1/1     Running   0          23m

NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/cert-manager           ClusterIP   10.245.180.136   <none>        9402/TCP   23m
service/cert-manager-webhook   ClusterIP   10.245.12.51     <none>        443/TCP    23m

NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/cert-manager              1/1     1            1           23m
deployment.apps/cert-manager-cainjector   1/1     1            1           23m
deployment.apps/cert-manager-webhook      1/1     1            1           23m

NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-86b4798576              1         1         1       23m
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-cainjector-85656d565c   1         1         1       23m
replicaset.apps/cert-manager-webhook-8665f985d6      1         1         1       23m
```

[Cluster Issuer CRD in Kubernetes Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kQh6.png)

Output of `kubectl describe crd clusterissuers.cert-manager.io`:

```
Name:         clusterissuers.cert-manager.io
Namespace:    
Labels:       app=cert-manager
              app.kubernetes.io/instance=cert-manager
              app.kubernetes.io/name=cert-manager
              app.kubernetes.io/version=v1.7.2
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/inject-ca-from-secret: cert-manager/cert-manager-webhook-ca
API Version:  apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
Kind:         CustomResourceDefinition
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-06-06T13:47:43Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:acceptedNames:
          f:categories:
          f:kind:
          f:listKind:
          f:plural:
          f:singular:
        f:conditions:
          k:{"type":"Established"}:
            .:
            f:lastTransitionTime:
            f:message:
            f:reason:
            f:status:
            f:type:
          k:{"type":"NamesAccepted"}:
            .:
            f:lastTransitionTime:
            f:message:
            f:reason:
            f:status:
            f:type:
    Manager:      kube-apiserver
    Operation:    Update
    Subresource:  status
    Time:         2022-06-06T13:47:43Z
    API Version:  apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:cert-manager.io/inject-ca-from-secret:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
        f:labels:
          .:
          f:app:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name:
          f:app.kubernetes.io/version:
      f:spec:
        f:conversion:
          .:
          f:strategy:
        f:group:
        f:names:
          f:categories:
          f:kind:
          f:listKind:
          f:plural:
          f:singular:
        f:scope:
        f:versions:
    Manager:         kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2022-06-06T13:47:43Z
  Resource Version:  149104003
  UID:               d5e2e5ed-4c3d-48e9-b6fc-72e621ad34b4
Spec:
  Conversion:
    Strategy:  None
  Group:       cert-manager.io
  Names:
    Categories:
      cert-manager
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    List Kind:  ClusterIssuerList
    Plural:     clusterissuers
    Singular:   clusterissuer
  Scope:        Cluster
    Served:    true
    Storage:   true
    Subresources:
      Status:
Status:
  Accepted Names:
    Categories:
      cert-manager
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    List Kind:  ClusterIssuerList
    Plural:     clusterissuers
    Singular:   clusterissuer
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-06-06T13:47:43Z
    Message:               no conflicts found
    Reason:                NoConflicts
    Status:                True
    Type:                  NamesAccepted
    Last Transition Time:  2022-06-06T13:47:44Z
    Message:               the initial names have been accepted
    Reason:                InitialNamesAccepted
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Established
  Stored Versions:
    v1
Events:  <none>
```

Comment: Why is it *obviously* wrong?

Comment: Because the typo in cert-manger, missing an A in manager. And the internal DNS for a service is just 1 time cert-manager. So it should be ```cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443```

Comment: can you list the resources in that namespace?

Comment: I added the output of ```kubectl get all -n cert-manager```

Comment: how does the crd for clusterissuer look like? How did you set this up? Did you use helm?

Comment: I used both ways, with helm and without. Now I have installed cert-manager with one manifest containing all the crds. The crd looks fine, I added a picture of the crd in the kubernetes dashboard

Comment: well, the crd on the dashboard isnt all that useful. Consider pasting the actual crd here. the you you get with `kubectl get ...`. Also pease dont post images if it can be avoided. And make sure you delete the crds when you change versions and so on. crd are most of the time not automatically removed.

Comment: Sure, added the output (a little tweaked for the amount of characters). Its a fresh install of cert-manager.

Comment: like i said, fresh install != fresh crd. You need to remove crds manually after something like helm uninstall. And please do get -o yaml, describe has most of the time not as much useful information.